# IGB Stack Flair – A dynamic flair for Stack Exchange sites

Tags: app, script, javascript, api-v2.2, flair

[image: Profile for Gerold Broser on Stack Exchange]

[A dynamic flair for Stack Exchange sites](//sourceforge.net/projects/igbstackflair/) inspired by [Stack Exchange's native User Flairs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/).

### With Advanced Features

- Including Stack Exchange sites with more than 101 reputation (compared to 200).
- Detailed reputation summary (compared to K and M abbreviations).
- Detailed statistics about Questions, Answers, Reputation, Gold, Silver and Bronze badges for each included site (compared to `Exception in thread "stackoverflow" NullPointerException at com.stackoverflow.users.flair.UserFlair.showSiteInfoTooltip(UserFlair:1)`.
- Updated in real-time (compared to 24–36 hrs), with update retention period due to max. 300 requests to SE's database per day .
  [image: IGB Stack Flair – A dynamic flair for Stack Exchange sites]

### About

- [IGB Stack Flair](//sourceforge.net/projects/igbstackflair/) at [SourceForge](//sourceforge.net/)
- [How to include IGB Stack Flair in your web page](//sourceforge.net/p/igbstackflair/code/ci/master/tree/v1/igbstackflair.html)
- How to integrate IGB Stack Flair into your Wikipedia user page:
- see [Gerold 'Geri' Broser's en:Wikipedia user page](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Gerold_Broser)
- see [wiki page for Wikipedia Integration](//sourceforge.net/p/igbstackflair/wiki/Wikipedia%20Integration/)

### Platform

- Any browser capable of [HTML5](//www.w3.org/TR/html5/) and [JavaScript](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

### Contact

- [geribro at SourceForge](//sourceforge.net/u/geribro/profile/)

### Code

- [IGB Stack Flair project Code page](//sourceforge.net/p/igbstackflair/code/ci/master/tree/) at [SourceForge](//sourceforge.net/).

Developed using:

- [Eclipse JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT)](//projects.eclipse.org/projects/webtools.jsdt)
- [EGit](//www.eclipse.org/egit/)
- [Notepad++](//www.notepad-plus-plus.org/)
- [git](//git-for-windows.github.io/)
- [Stack Exchange API](//api.stackexchange.com/)
- [WinSCP](//winscp.net/)
- [Firefox](//www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)
- [Opera](//www.opera.com/)
- [Chrome](//www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/)

### License

- [GNU General Public License version 3](//www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html)